# Add multiple sort with <ReferenceInput>

Tags: reactjs, api-platform.com, react-admin

Could someone help me with this: how i can use multiple fields to sort my source ?

```
<ReferenceInput label="Version" source="version" reference="versions" key="version" validate={[required()]} sort={{field: 'letter', order:'ASC'}}>
    <SelectInput optionText={version => `${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.patch}.${version.letter}`} />                        
</ReferenceInput>
```

Comment: Would post code for `ReferenceInput`?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what do you mean !

Comment: Is `ReferenceInput` your custom code? or part of a framework? Unless there is code or documentation available for it, people won't be able to help

Comment: Is part of the framework (React admin), and here is the doc : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#referenceinput

Comment: Have you tried sort={{field: 'letter', order:'ASC'}, {field: 'nameofsecondfield', order:'ASC'}}?